# Can you set own prices when selling music on iTunes?

Tags: app-store-connect, price

Can you set your own track/album prices when selling music on iTunes?

I was able to find answers on several forums (not on Apple's website/KBs), but they were contradictory (some say that it's $0.99 automatically, some that you can choose the price).

Can someone clarify the pricing parameters an artist can use on the iTunes store?

Answer (score 3):

Check [this](http://support.apple.com/en-is/HT201162) info in official Apple site.[This](http://www.tunecore.com/index/sell_your_music_on_itunes) & [this](http://help.tunecore.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/37) interesting sources. I think it could help.

---

[image]

If you already have an account with iTunes for music distribution, you can review your pricing options in the legal documents by logging in to https://itunesconnect.apple.com/ and then selecting Agreements, Tax, and Banking - if you don't have a selling account, you can apply and if accepted, you will get to review the legal agreements and then decide to proceed with signing them if you wish.

- https://www.apple.com/itunes/working-itunes/sell-content/music-faq.html